# GeoServer: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

Tags: geoserver, postgresql

I am trying to add a PostGIS database a data store in my GeoServer installation but I keep getting this error:

```
Error creating data store, check the parameters.
Error message: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory
 ( The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured
   the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, 
   and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.)
```

Here is the code in my `pg_Hba.conf` file.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     md5
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all     all             30.19.120.49/31            md5
```

Has anyone had this issue before? Was it solvable by adding an entry to `pg_hba.conf`?

Since my GeoServer resides on http://localhost:8080/ I tried adding:

[image: Error Image Attached]

Comment: how do you authenticate on postgres?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210167/unable-to-connect-to-postgress-db-due-to-the-authentication-type-10-is-not-suppo for a possible solution, if that works please ask GeoTools to upgrade the jdbc driver

Comment: @IanTurton I tried the solution but doesn't work.

Comment: can you add the relevant part of your `postgresql.conf` file then

Comment: @IanTurton https://justpaste.it/7v0q2 (path tto my postfresql.conf) file

Comment: you did restart postgres after that change?

Comment: @IanTurton I tried restarting but doesn't help, same error.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the same problem by:

- Change the METHOD from "md5" to "trust" in pg_Hba.conf
- Download the last "PostgreSQL JDBC 4.2 Driver, 42.2.20" from
  https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html and paste in C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.15.1\lib

I´m not sure, but it is supposed to have lower security if we change the METHOD, so I suppose that there is a better way than this, but at the moment it works fine for me.